# Get a modifiable reserved memory in linux binary using nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to change data inside my nasm's `section .bss` in my tiny x86 binary, but it's not working.

I have a tiny ELF header for linux binary (something like the last one from [here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)) and predefined string prints to linux console fine:

```
global _start

BITS 32

        org     0x00010000

        ; tiny ELF header

_start:

        mov     ecx, string1
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     dx, 8
        mov     ax, 4
        int     0x80

        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ebx, eax
        inc     eax
        int     0x80

section .data
string1 db  "Hello!", 0xa
```

But I need a modifiable text buffer. I have created

```
section .bss
printable:           resb    19 * 18
```

at the end of my source and started to modify them

```
        cld
        mov esi, string1
        mov al, 0x20
        mov ecx, 0x01
        rep stosb
```

an this failed with segmentation fault. Doesn't matter is it one byte change with `mov [esi],al` or block with `rep stosb`, `string1` or `printable` memory addresses - everything crashes with segmentation fault.

What's wrong?

As a result I want a modifiable reserved memory, but not placed inside of my binary. So I want to build text by the code.

Comment: `esi` and `stosb` do not go together, you want `edi`. And `string1` is not in your nobits/bss section. Not sure what else is wrong though.

Comment: Also please show your full test case, not just snippets. It may be relevant in which section you placed your code.

Comment: Also add the assembler and linker commands that you use to build.

Comment: GDB should show you the fault address.  The fact that it's not what's in the register you were expecting (ESI) is your clue that the problem is something other than non-writeable memory.  But `mov [esi], al` works if you have the address in ESI.  Unless the `org     0x00010000` is making your whole program not work?

Comment: I'm surprised that assembles and links with `nasm -felf32`.  It doesn't for me, with NASM 2.16, it says `error: parser: instruction expected` on the `org` line because that's only valid for `-f bin` flat binaries, not for `-f elf32`.  Use a linker script if you want your program to load at a weird location.  (`0x10000` is just barely above https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr so it should work without modifying that kernel setting.)

Comment: Please forget about full or short registers, just because you don't need to init full reg when it's 0 on binary start. I got what you mean, but the problem is not here. I have noticed that the problem is in my short ELF header. The shortest one (32 bytes) from the last example from [here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) do not allows me to modify map if I set `p_flags` to 7, while [this 82 bytes header](http://www.sizecoding.org/wiki/Linux#ELF_Header_Information) works if i set p_flags to 7. I am working with this question and I'll post full details a bit later.

Comment: PS: my nasm compile command is: nasm -f bin -o binary main.asm. In place of `tiny ELF header` comment I pasted both examples of tiny ELF headers and only one of them allows me to modify memory (`p_flags` is `7`).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov     dx, 8
> mov     ax, 4
> ```

You need to use 32-bit registers

> ```
> cld
> mov esi, string1
> mov al, 0x20
> mov ecx, 0x01
> rep stosb
> ```

The ESI register is not an input to `rep stosb`. Use EDI for that. Failure to setup EDI is what causes the segmentation fault.
eg. To copy *string1* to *printable*:

```
mov  edi, printable
mov  esi, string1
mov  ecx, 7
rep movsb
```

Another example to wipe *printable*:

```
mov  edi, printable
mov  ecx, 19 * 18
mov  al, 0
rep stosb
```

You can assume the direction flag is clear (DF=0). No need to `cld` all the time, except perhaps once at program start...